# Is there a \urlstyle{tt} (or something else) for \href to make it the same font as \url links?

Tags: links

Is there a `\urlstyle{tt}` (or something else to that effect) for `\href` to make it the same font as `\url` links? I'm happy with any monospace font, as long as they both (`\url` and `\href`) show up the same.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `\nolinkurl` inside the second argument of `\href`:

```
\href{http://mirror.ctan.org/foo/bar}{\nolinkurl{CTAN:foo/bar}}
```

Comment: Or simply with `\texttt{CTAN:foo/bar}`/`\ttfamily CTAN:foo/bar` in the second part of `\href`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Yes, that works but for a document with lots of `\href`, it is tedious to change them all (at least by hand).