# How to patch \href to look like \url?

Tags: hyperref, patching

There are at least two questions, that ask for this without mentioning it explicitly, so there we go.

Neither [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426877/) [nor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104294/) actually answer the questions, how to make `\href` style the same way as `\url` - without additional commands in the second argument of `\href`. I've seen Heiko's comment [in another related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/202128#comment471123_202129), that `\href` is much more complicated, since it supports images and whatnot. But wouldn't patching `\href` to additionally include a `\texttt` be rather benign?

However, `\href` looks rather complicated; how would one patch it the least invasive way to sneak in an enforced monospaced fontstyle?

My naive solution/MWE simply redefines `\href` and inserts a `\texttt`, which works fine in the trivial test case(s), but I have no idea about consequences in more complex usages of hyperref.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\begin{document}
\bigskip
url: \url{www.yahoo.com}

original href: \href{http://www.yahoo.com/}{www.yahoo.com}

\bigskip
url: \url{www.yahoo.com}

nolink-url href: \href{http://www.yahoo.com/}{\nolinkurl{www.yahoo.com}}

% patch it - usually in the preamble of course...
\LetLtxMacro\oldhref\href
\renewcommand{\href}[3][]{%
  \oldhref[#1]{#2}{\texttt{#3}}
}

\bigskip
url: \url{www.yahoo.com}

patched href: \href{http://www.yahoo.com/}{www.yahoo.com}

\medskip
yay!

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

What are possible consequences of this (test cases that would break it) and how to do it better?

Comment: Your patch will break if the url contains special chars like `#` or `%`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add \ttfamily to \href like this. I added a key option to change it locally too

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\define@key{href}{font}{#1}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xpatch}
\newcommand\hrefdefaultfont{\ttfamily}
\xpatchcmd\href{\setkeys{href}{#1}}{\setkeys{href}{font=\hrefdefaultfont,#1}}{}{\fail}

\begin{document}
\bigskip
url: \url{www.yahoo.com}

original href: \href{http://www.yahoo.com/}{www.yahoo.com}

some text
\href[font=\rmfamily\bfseries]{http://www.yahoo.com/}{www.yahoo.com}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution breaks line breaking (no pun intended).

Comment: As does your texttt solution. Without an url command there are no url like breaks.

Comment: Well, yeah, that's why I called my PoC naive and made it part of the question :) I don't get the meaning of your second sentence. Without the patch URLs in `\href` get wrapped - no direct `\url` command needed. It overshoots more but at least it does something. With your patch there is no wrapping at all.

Comment: no, there is no wrapping is www.yahoo.com, with or without the patch. When forcing the font to ttfamily you disable hyphenation as ttfamily normally doesn't have hyphenation. You can use `\newcommand\hrefdefaultfont{\ttfamily\hyphenchar\font=\defaulthyphenchar}` to enable it, but it will only work for normal words, not for url like stuff with periods and slashes. url don't use hyphenation but mathbreaks.

Comment: A simple www.yahoo.com link doesn't with `\url` but it would break at slashes (and hyphens if enabled) at least. I didn't know that there is no hyphenation at all in tt - that probably explains a lot actually :D After more thought I think I want something different altogether anyway. Thanks for the insights!

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer my question but I think it might still be useful to some...
After some thought I ended up with something completely different: a `\url` that has two arguments with the same basic idea as `\href` but where the second one is optional:

```
\documentclass{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\LetLtxMacro\oldurl\url
\RenewDocumentCommand \url{mg}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
    \oldurl{#1}%
  }{%
    \href{#1}{\nolinkurl{#2}}%
  }
}

\begin{document}

\smallskip
\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1ex}

\smallskip
\noindent url\hfill\hspace{0.6\linewidth}\url{https://www.yahoo.com/break/me}

\smallskip
\noindent url\#2\hfill\hspace{0.6\linewidth}\url{https://www.yahoo.com/break-me/please}{www.yahoo.com/break/me/please}

\smallskip
\noindent url\#2\hfill\hspace{0.6\linewidth}\url{https://www.yahoo.com/break-me/please}{www.yahoo.com/break-me/please}

\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1ex}

\end{document}
```

With this you can easily create links that are formatted the same as with a plain `\url` but are still able to customize the displayed characters (e.g., leaving out the `https://`). Also the interface is much nicer and easy to remember - no need to repeat the `\nolinkurl` all the time as in other solutions.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is also broken by hashes and I can't find a good solution -> new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499651